# How to handle OpenSSL.SSL.Error while using twisted.web.client.Agent on Facebook graph api?

Tags: python, ssl, twisted

I am running the ff. code from a virtualenv on Mac OS X (Yosemite):

```
    # testfb.py
    from twisted.internet import reactor
    from twisted.python import log
    from twisted.web.client import Agent

    GRAPH_API = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5"

    def stop(_):
        reactor.stop()

    def get_me(access_token):
        agent = Agent(reactor)
        uri = "{}/me?access_token={}".format(GRAPH_API, access_token)
        log.msg("uri:" + uri)
        return agent.request("GET", uri)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        import sys
        access_token = sys.argv[1]
        d = get_me(access_token)
        d.addErrback(log.err)
        d.addCallback(stop)
        reactor.run()
```

And I get:

```
    Failure: twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'certificate verify failed')]>]
```

I don't have this issue when I call the uri in curl.

BTW, I also installed service_identity using pip on the virtualenv.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably don't have any OpenSSL trust roots configured.  This used to happen automatically by accident because [Cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) linked against the built-in version of OpenSSL from OS X. Since the headers for that version were removed in El Capitan, Cryptography now ships wheels with their own built-in version of pyOpenSSL.

This is a bug in Twisted, and we know about it; you can read more about it here: https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/6372.  It's been open for a while; because it worked by accident for a long time, it hasn't been a high priority.  Thanks to bug reports from folks like you, this is changing...

In the meanwhile, though, you have two possible options.

One is that you can install OpenSSL from [Homebrew](http://brew.sh), which will automatically put some certificate authority certificates in the default location that Cryptography's OpenSSL is already looking for them, with `brew install openssl`.  (You can see these certificate authority certificates in `/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem` after installing it)

Another is that you can get some certificates from [Certifi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/certifi), and then set the ([undocumented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286265/how-to-use-ssl-cert-file-for-openssl-windows-openssl-1-0-1c)) environment variable that tells OpenSSL to look for them, by doing, for example, `export SSL_CERT_FILE="$(python -m certifi)"` in your shell before invoking your Python program.

Sorry for the, and I hope this answers your question!

Comment: I am using macports and I tried a few times re-installing openssl and py27-pyopenssl but no luck there. 'certifi', OTOH, worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: I said "homebrew" and not "macports" on purpose :). The certificate authority extraction code is specific to homebrew, not something related to OpenSSL.  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/openssl.rb#L113  That is why I listed certifi as an alternate option :).

Comment: Glad I could help, though!

Comment: Had the same problem. I tried the certifi, didn't work for me. But doing the brew install openssl worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: brew didn't work since I already had openssl installed, but certifi did the trick