# After installing Ruby 2.3.1, I cannot install any Gems on Win10: SSL error

Tags: rubygems

After installing Ruby 2.3.1 x64, I cannot install any Gems on Win10 because of a SSL error.   I found **lots of articles on the net about how to fix** it but none of them work.   Where is the source of truth!

```
C:\Users\djangofan>gem install rubygems-update
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rubygems-update' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 
          errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
     (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

And i have connectivity:

```
C:\Users\djangofan>ping rubygems.org

Pinging rubygems.org [151.101.128.70] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 151.101.128.70: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=58
```

Comment: try it with http://rubyinstaller.org/

Comment: yes, thats the one I used, version 2.3.1 directly from that same website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working by setting my source to http instead of https when connecting to rubygems.org. In a command prompt:

```
> gem sources -r https://rubygems.org -a http://rubygems.org
```

I tried manually setting a secure certificate (from [How to use SSL_CERT_FILE for OpenSSL Windows (OpenSSL 1.0.1c)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286265/how-to-use-ssl-cert-file-for-openssl-windows-openssl-1-0-1c)) but that didn't work for me.

Comment: Interesting thought. Ill try this later after I get back to my Windows PC. Thanks.

Comment: Those instructions were NOT straight-forward.  Here is what I had to do:  1. Install Latest 64bit Ruby 2.3.1, 2. extract 64bit RubyInstaller DevKit into that Ruby installation folder, 3.  Add Ruby/bin  and Ruby/mingw/bin to the PATH.,  4.  run the command you listed above.   5.  Then, it works.